# How do I setup a hassle-free developer machine after installing Apache in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, lamp

I just installed a LAMP server in a fresh Ubuntu system.

The main problem I have is that the webroot is at "/var/www", and my default username doesn't have access to write there. I could be `sudo`-ing all the time, but thats quite a pain. I've tried playing with permissions and symbolic links, but I never seem to get through the problem.

How do I setup a new developer machine so that I can quick and efficiently start developing right off the bat?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Now it sounds like you're [asking for opinion](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) and it may be put on hold. However, you can rewrite it to ask how to solve specific problem (permission issues).

Comment: @gronostaj To me it looks like that's the gist of the question, "best" is being defined clearly here, so this question is fine.

Comment: I've edited your question to better match what we're looking for here at Super User.  Feel free to change, or even roll-back if you disagree.  Ultimately I feel that this is a valid and good question (cc @slhck)

Answer (score 2):

**Change /var/www**

I would recommend you edit the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and change the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` to point to something along the lines of

```
DocumentRoot /home/USERNAME/web/
```

and

```
<directory /home/USERNAME/web>
```

instead of the ones with /var/www in them

**Userdirs**

Alternatively you can enable Userdirs, by simply

```
sudo mv /etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.* /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

Then you can access your `/home/USERNAME/public_html` directory from `http://127.0.0.1/~USERNAME`

Note: Both of these methods require you to restart apache, you can do so with

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Good suggestions. For simplicity, the `userdir` module can be enabled with `sudo a2enmod userdir`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a group of users that has write permissions to the `/var/www` directory. For example, `www-users`:

```
sudo addgroup www-users
```

Then, add yourself to that group:

```
sudo adduser $(whoami) www-users
```

Finally give ownership to the group, and set group-writable permissions:

```
sudo chgrp www-users /var/www
sudo chmod –R 775 /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Now, you will be able to create and modify files in `/var/www` as long as they also belong to your group. If you need Apache to have write access, you can `adduser www-data www-users` to give it write permissions as well.

Comment: Is there a way that this could be written up as a script, that runs after a fresh install of the system?  Because I think that's ultimately the goal of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and the best solution I have found is vagrant.

http://www.vagrantup.com

Basically Vagrant is software that integrates with virtual box, and allows you to quickly spin up a VM. It is then very easy to map the /var/www directory, to the project home. Any changes made to that directory, instantly show up live on the web server.

Vagrant advantages:

- Standardize environments for all developers though box images.
- Automatic symbolic linking of folders
- Quick setup/teardown